# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource even if I use allow all origins on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, cors

I am trying to post form data to my REST API. Even if I allow all origins I get a cors error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mydomain.com/route' from
>   origin 'https://subdomain.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

This is my middleware on my express server:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "POST"
  );

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");

  next();
});
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: app.use is written before app.get('/')  ?

Comment: Yes, app.use is written before app.post()

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the Header in your response in the Server https://subdomain.mydomain.com

This worked for me in Asp.net Web API

Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");